# How to fix loop issue for a nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an assignment in Python where the user looks up a password from a nested list. I was given most of the code I just need to finish it out. The code I have works enough for me to turn in the assignment but I would like an explanation on what I did wrong. If I choose "google" which is the second in the list it

I have read everything I can find about nested lists and loops and not been able to find what I need. I have take out the nested for-loop and it only made it worst. I know it is just my lack of understanding on how to do this.

```
        print("Which website do you want to lookup the password for?")
        for keyvalue in passwords:
            print(keyvalue[0])
        passwordToLookup = input()

        for i in passwords:
            if passwordToLookup in i:
                print("Your encrypted password is: " + i[1])
                print("Your unencrypted password is: " + passwordEncrypt(i[1], -16))
                break
            else:
                print("Login does not exist.")
```

I only want it to look for the users input, which is "google". Third line from the bottom of output says "Login does not exist" which is for "yahoo", don't think this should be here, but not sure. Just need a little explanation or direction.

```
What would you like to do:
 1. Open password file
 2. Lookup a password
 3. Add a password
 4. Save password file
 5. Print the encrypted password list (for testing)
 6. Quit program
Please enter a number (1-4)
2
Which website do you want to lookup the password for?
yahoo
google
google
Login does not exist.
Your encrypted password is: CoIushujSetu
Your unencrypted password is: MySecretCode
```

Thanks!

Comment: Edited it maybe its a little clearer, if not let me know. Thanks!

Comment: might help if you show your data structure also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Printing the database has no importance to your problem.

What's happening is that if you look at this code:

```
        for i in passwords:
            if passwordToLookup in i:
                print("Your encrypted password is: " + i[1])
                print("Your unencrypted password is: " + passwordEncrypt(i[1], -16))
                break
            else:
                print("Login does not exist.")
```

You can see that it will print `Login does not exist.` until it finds it. To fix it, you'll want to use a boolean and wait until the loop is done until you run `print("Login does not exist.")`. So, it'd look like this:

```
        doesNotExist = True
        for i in passwords:
            if passwordToLookup in i:
                print("Your encrypted password is: " + i[1])
                print("Your unencrypted password is: " + passwordEncrypt(i[1], -16))
                doesNotExist = False
                break
        if doesNotExist:
            print ("Login does not exist.")
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try when I get home, I couldn't figure out how to stop that, when I add more passwords, it would do the same for those.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you can set it as "Solved"!

Comment: I will as soon as I can figure out how to do that, sorry new guy!

Comment: Thank you John I looked everywhere for something that said Solved.